# df.apply(): AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, attributeerror, nonetype

I am encountering an AttributeError while running the following commands in Python:

```
start = datetime.now()

df_no_dup["tag_count"] = df_no_dup["Tags"].apply(lambda text: len(text.split(" ")))
# adding a new feature number of tags per question
print("Time taken to run this cell :", datetime.now() - start)
df_no_dup.head()
```

The error message is as follows:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I am trying to calculate the number of tags per question using the apply function, but it seems like there might be instances where the "Tags" column contains NoneType objects. How can I modify the code to handle such cases and avoid the AttributeError?

Any assistance in resolving this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to look at the value in df_no_dup["Tags"] because split is a function applied to strings, and you may have a value of None

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how do I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are sure that the values you are dealing with are all strings then you can make a judgment

```py
from datetime import datetime


start = datetime.now()

df_no_dup["tag_count"] = df_no_dup["Tags"].apply(lambda text: len(text.split(" ") if text else 0))
# adding a new feature number of tags per question
print("Time taken to run this cell :", datetime.now() - start)
df_no_dup.head()
```

Answer (score -1):

df_no_dup["Tags"] is having None value. Just add an if clause to guard it.

```
    start = datetime.now()

    if df_no_dup["Tags"] is not None:
        df_no_dup["tag_count"] = df_no_dup["Tags"].apply(lambda text: len(text.split(" ")))
    # adding a new feature number of tags per question
    print("Time taken to run this cell :", datetime.now() - start)
    df_no_dup.head()
```